# How to get data from a pandas df based on condition from other df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df1 which has columns as Id, source and timestamp and df2 has columns as Id, source, timestamp, values. I want to populate 'value' from df2 on df1 only if the timestamp on df2 is less than that on df1. I thought of using a for loop but it would be very slow as df2 is very large. sharing sample code below. Any hint on how to handle this efficiently would be helpful.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = [[201, 'a1', 100], [201, 'a2', 100] ,[201, 'a3', 100], [202, 'b1', 88], [202, 'b2', 88]]
data2 = [[201, 'a1', 102, 2.1], [201, 'a1', 100, 2.2], [201, 'a1', 99, 2.9], [201, 'a2', 102, 3], [201, 'a2', 98, 3], [201, 'a3', 100, 76], [202, 'b1', 88, 9.1], [202, 'b2', 87, 2.3]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Id', 'source', 'timestamp'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Id', 'source', 'timestamp', 'value'])
abcd = 100
    
output = [[201, 'a1', 99, 2.9], [201, 'a2', 98, 3] ,[201, 'a3', 'NA', 'NA'], [202, 'b1', 'NA', 'NA'], [202, 'b2', 87, 2.3]]
expected_output = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = ['Id', 'source', 'timestamp', 'value'])
```

[image]

Comment: for me I think I will join df1 and df2 based on Id and source, and then I will filter it where timestamp1>timestamp2, but I dont know how large is df2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do **[`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)**

```
pd.merge_asof(
    df1.sort_values('timestamp').rename(columns={'timestamp': 'ts'}), 
    df2.sort_values('timestamp'), by=['Id', 'source'], left_on='ts',
    right_on='timestamp', direction='backward', allow_exact_matches=False
).drop(columns=['ts'])
```

---

```
    Id source  timestamp  value
0  202     b1        NaN    NaN
1  202     b2       87.0    2.3
2  201     a1       99.0    2.9
3  201     a2       98.0    3.0
4  201     a3        NaN    NaN
```